# How to alternate style (background color ) for div inside div

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

How to alternate style (background color with jquery) for div inside div with id="container" alternately ( even and odd ) if I have HTML like this

```
<div id="container">
   <div></div> 
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
...
</div>
```

I know with table like

```
#tbl_users tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC;}
#tbl_users tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF;}
```

but how to div apply something like this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try:

```
div#container div:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC;}
div#container div:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF;}
```

nth-child should work regardless of the tag.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#container>div:odd').css("background-color", "#ff0000");
$('#container>div:even').css("background-color", "#00ff00");
```

Comment: Nice solution for IE7!

Answer (score 2):

It works exactly the same way with divs. With the above structure, you could get the same effect with:

```
#container div:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC;}
#container div:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF;}
```

Comment: @pistacchio Correct you are, but neither does the CSS he usually uses for tables.

Comment: Why is it that people always nag about certain selectors/properties having poor browser support when obviously a lot of people including the OP don't care?

Answer (score 0):

using the same trick:

```
#container div:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC;}
#container div:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container">
   <div>A</div> 
   <div>B</div>
   <div>C</div>
   <div>D</div>
</div>

div#container div:nth-child(even) {background: #FF00CC;}
div#container div:nth-child(odd) {background: #CC00FF;}
```

Please try this link http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpbz